# Passing a file to POST request in Play Framework

Tags: java, rest, playframework

We're using Play Framework 2.0. to serve REST requests. We would like to be able to pass a file to a POST request and be able to process it in our Contoller.

I ended up with the following:

```
GET /customer/:id/photos    controllers.PhotosController.addPhoto(id: Integer, page: String)
```

I tried to get to the content of the file in the Controller code but without luck.

I was sending the POST request in the following way:

```
curl.exe -X GET localhost:9000/customer/23/photos?page=Sun.jpg
```

Any ideas how to handle this case?

Comment: Now I've noticed that I'm using incorrect url. So the question is how can I simulate sending a file content with curl?

Comment: The command *curl.exe -X GET* is not making a POST... Take a look at http://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request and http://paulstimesink.com/2005/06/29/http-post-with-curl/

Comment: Also, your controller is receiving a *String* instead of *File*

Answer (score 0):

```
//add this line in you controller

static play.data.Form<Model> modelForm = form(Model.class);

public static Result addPostSave(){
    try{
      MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
      FilePart picture = body.getFile("picture");
      File pic = picture.getFile();
if(filledForm.hasErrors()){
              return ok(addPost.render(postForm));
          }else{              
              Post post = new Post();
              post.picture = pic;
              post.save();
              return ok(index.render("The image is created"));
          }  
    }catch(IOException e){
       return ok(e.to_string)
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your controller should look something like:

```
public static void addPhoto(Integer id, File page){}
```

The route:

```
POST /customer/:id/photos controllers.PhotosController.addPhoto(id: Integer, page: File)
```

And your test request should look something like:

```
curl.exe -F page=@Sun.jpg localhost:9000/customer/23/photos
```

(Tested in play 1.2.3)

Answer (score 0):

In Play 2.0 you do it like that:

**Controller** (just an example):

```
public static Result addPhoto(Integer id){
    MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    FilePart file = body.getFile("page");
    System.out.println(file.getFilename());
    System.out.println(file.getFile().getAbsoluteFile());
    return ok();
}
```

**routes**:

```
POST    /addphoto/:id   controllers.PhotosController.addPhoto(id: java.lang.Integer)
```

**curl command**:

```
curl --header "enctype -> multipart/form-data" -F page=@/path/to/file localhost:9000/addphoto/23
```